# Arquillian JMS embedded

Tags: jms, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

Seen examples (very [few](https://community.jboss.org/message/870631?_sscc=t)) of setting up Arquillian to test jms with remote profiles. Is it possible to test against an embedded container.  Doesn't matter right now what the embedded implementation is (i.e. tomee, wildfly etc.).  Would love a link or tip how to set this up via ShrinkWrap and an embedded configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with tomee (embedded, remote) and openejb (really embedded ;)). Conf looks like properties of this file: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomee/tomee/trunk/arquillian/arquillian-tomee-tests/arquillian-tomee-jms-tests/src/test/resources/arquillian.xml, basically tomee/openejb properties to define a broker, queue etc...see http://tomee.apache.org/containers-and-resources.html for details

Comment: Wrote a GitHub example (https://github.com/SwedishConnection/Arquillian-MQSeries)